# Why did Blofeld tell Hans to keep the keys to spaceship's self-destruct?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, you-only-live-twice

When Blofeld leaves the control center in *You Only Live Twice*, he gives the keys to self-destruct to his bodyguard, Hans.

Why did he do that, as opposed to just throwing the key out into the piranha pool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Blofeld gave Hans, who was his trusted henchman, keys to self-destruct to blow up the spaceship.

When Blofeld gave him keys to self-destruct, there wasn't piranha pool. However, why would he ask him (Hans) to throw the keys when he wanted to destroy the spaceship once they captured the space shuttle.

Here's a snippet of conversation between Blofeld and Hans.

> **Blofeld:** Hans, our job will soon be done. Blow them up as soon as they
> have captured the Americans.
>
> Here is the key to operate the exploder button.

That's here Bond interrupts their plan and destroys the spaceship before it could capture the American space shuttle.